# startActivity not waiting for Alert button to be clicked

Tags: java, android, alert

I have a dialog box that prompts a user to confirm a deletion.

After the user hits delete a simple alert pops up. Im needing to redirect to a new activity but the startActivity fires off before I get the chance to click "OK" on the confirmation alert. Ive added a comment where it messes up. Any ideas?

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new 
AlertDialog.Builder(EventDetails.this);
                    alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete 
your Issue?")
                            .setTitle(R.string.app_name)
                            .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    Configs.showPD("Please wait...", EventDetails.this);

                                    eventObj.put(Configs.ISSUES_DELETED_BY, "Deleted By User");
                                    Date now = new Date();

                                    eventObj.put(Configs.ISSUES_DELETED_DATE, now);
                                    eventObj.put(Configs.ISSUES_DELETED, true);
                                    eventObj.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                                            if (e == null) {
                                                Configs.hidePD();
                                                Configs.simpleAlert("Issue deleted!", EventDetails.this);



                                                // Does not wait for me to click "OK" after "Issue deleted!"
                                               Intent intent = new Intent(EventDetails.this, MyIssues.class);
                                               startActivity(intent);


                                            }


                                        }



                                    });
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
                    alert.create().show();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where is simpleAlert code

Comment: Inside of simpleAlert() there's probably some code that displays the alert. In that call, I'm willing to wager there's a place to put a callback. That's there the startActivity() call would go. What you have here likely has nothing to do with the alert except for displaying it before kicking off the activity.

Comment: You both were correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! JoeHz was correct.

Here is the code for anyone having this issue.

```
   AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(EventDetails.this);
                                                alert.setMessage("Issue deleted!")
                                                        .setTitle(R.string.app_name)
                                                        .setIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                                                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                                        Intent intent = new Intent(EventDetails.this, MyIssues.class);
                                                                        startActivity(intent);
                                                                        finish();
                                                                    }
                                                                });
```